# Ошибка бота telegram «Conflict: another webhook is active.»

Tags: telegram-bot

Поставил хук для бота telegram
`https://api.telegram.org/bot1XXXXXX:token/setwebhook?url=https://test.com/hook2.php`

При обращении на 
    `https://api.telegram.org/bot1XXXXXX:token/getUpdates`

для бота получаю ошибку -

> Conflict: another webhook is active.

Пробую сбрасывать хук `https://api.telegram.org/bot1XXXXXX:token/setwebhook?url=`

Тогда ошибка пропадает, но когда снова ставлю хук, то история повторяется. Пробовал даже ставить другой хук, всё равно не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать метод getUpdates совместно с webhook'ами.
Определитесь, и используйте что-то одно.

Об этом сказано в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook):

> 1. You will not be able to receive updates using getUpdates for as long as an outgoing webhook is set up.